# Access Active Directory user groups from DMZ

Tags: c#, active-directory, dmz

I have a method that checks if a user is a member of a AD group. I tried using my own AD account as credentials and then I get some information about the userprincipal, like email etc. But when accessing the userprincipals groups I get the following error message:

> Exception:
>   MESSAGE: The server is not operational.
>   SOURCE: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
>   TARGETSITE: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ResultSet   GetGroupsMemberOf(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal)
>
> STACKTRACE:
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOf(Principal p)
>   at Authorization.AuthorizeAD.IsMemberOfGroup(String user)
>   at PVM.Controllers.SecurityController.IsMemberOfGroup(String user)
>
> InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.LoadDomainInfo()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.get_DnsForestName()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOf(Principal p)

Code:

```
public bool IsMemberOfGroup(string user) {
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ContextName, ContextContainer, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, "myUsername", "myPass")) {
        using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                context,
                IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                user)) {
            //I can access userPrincipal.DisplayName etc
                var groupName = "TestGroup"
                //This is where I get the error
                return userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I thought it could be a permission problem, but when using [ldp.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224543) from the server there was no problem querying active directory.

Everything works fine local. I've tried changing IIS AppPool login and so on, but now I ended up sending the credentials along with my PrincipalContext object.

Does anone have a clue what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved by using a PrincipalSearcher instead of UserPrincipal.IsMemberOf and then I did my own IsMemberOf().

```
private static bool IsMemberOf(PrincipalContext context, PrincipalSearcher searcher, string user,
        string groupToFind) {
        searcher.QueryFilter = new GroupPrincipal(context, groupToFind);

        var group = searcher.FindOne() as GroupPrincipal;
        if (group == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (group.GetMembers()
            .Select(member => member as UserPrincipal)
            .Where(principal => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal?.SamAccountName))
            .Any(principal => principal.SamAccountName.Equals(user))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```